# Internal error 500 when editing htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I edit my .htaccess file, the server retunrs a 500 error but I'm sure that my .htaccess is good. To test, I've just add a row at the end of the file and when I've uploaded it, I've had a 500 error. 
Have you any ideas ?

My .htaccess file :

```
#URL REWRITING
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


###############################################
#Rediriger tout le monde sauf une ip vers la page d'attente - Dé-COMMENTER EN CAS DE MAINTENANCE
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !uploads/(.*)$
#RewriteRule .* maintenance.html [L]

###########################################################

### RETRAIT DU / SI MIS A LA FIN URL ###

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

########################################

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DES TEXTURES ###
RewriteRule ^textures$ pages/textures.php [L]
RewriteRule ^textures/gerer/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ pages/textures.php?page=gerer&action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^textures/gerer$ pages/textures.php?page=gerer [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DES PILOTES ###
RewriteRule ^pilotes$ pages/pilotes.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DE CONNEXION ###
RewriteRule ^connexion$ pages/connexion.php [L]
RewriteRule ^connexion/requis$ pages/connexion.php?type=requis [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DE DECONNEXION ###
RewriteRule ^deconnexion$ scripts/logout.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DES VOLS ###
RewriteRule ^vols$ pages/vols.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DES VOLS EN COURS ###
RewriteRule ^live$ pages/live.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DE LA FLOTTE ###
RewriteRule ^flotte$ pages/flotte.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE DE LA GALERIE ###
RewriteRule ^galerie$ pages/galerie.php [L]
RewriteRule ^galerie/ajouter$ pages/galerie.php?action=add [L]
RewriteRule ^galerie/gerer$ pages/galerie.php?action=gerer [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LE CENTRE D HEBERGEMENT ###
RewriteRule ^upload$ pages/upload.php [L]
RewriteRule ^upload/administrer$ pages/upload.php?action=gerer [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE D'INSCRIPTION ###
RewriteRule ^inscription$ pages/inscription.php [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LA PAGE EQUIPE ###
RewriteRule ^personnel$ pages/personnel.php [L]
RewriteRule ^personnel/contact$ pages/personnel.php?action=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^personnel/contact/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ pages/personnel.php?action=contact&service=$1 [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS LES PAGES ADMIN ###
RewriteRule ^administration/utilisateurs$ pages/admin/utilisateurs.php [L]

RewriteRule ^administration$ pages/admin/admin.php [L]

RewriteRule ^administration/mail$ pages/admin/mail.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/mail/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ pages/admin/mail.php?action=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^administration/banniere$ pages/admin/banniere.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/banniere/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ pages/admin/banniere.php?action=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^administration/hubs$ pages/admin/hubs.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/hubs/gerer/editer/([0-9]+)$ pages/admin/hubs.php?action=modif_hub&hub_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/hubs/gerer$ pages/admin/hubs.php?action=gerer [L]

RewriteRule ^administration/securite$ pages/admin/securite.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/securite/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ pages/admin/securite.php?action=$1 [L]

### REDIRECTION VERS AVATARS ###
RewriteRule ^avatar/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).png$ scripts/avatar.php?pseudo=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^avatar/ivao=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).png$ scripts/avatar.php?pseudo=$1&param=ivao [L]
RewriteRule ^avatar/([0-9]+)=ivao=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).png$ scripts/avatar.php?pseudo=$2&param=ivao&width=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^avatar/([0-9]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).png$ scripts/avatar.php?pseudo=$2&width=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @anubhava I've replaced the `^^` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava `[Wed Jun 10 20:17:47 2015] [alert] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] [host xxx.fr] /homez.549/kkweosth/www/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf#URL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: ok remove all commented lines and retry

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't work

Comment: What does your Apache error.log say now

Comment: @anubhava `[Thu Jun 11 17:39:14 2015] [alert] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx] [host xxx.fr] /homez.549/kkweosth/www/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf#URL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Jun 11 17:39:31 2015] [alert] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx] [host xxx.fr] /homez.549/kkweosth/www/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: That means your .htaccess still has some strange characters. Edit it in a plain editor and remove these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied/pasted my htaccess content in a new notepad file. Then I saved it as *.htaccess* and I chose the *ANSI* charset.